# Calling an Activity from a broadcastreceiver, but keep it in the background

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an alarm set to trigger every *n* minutes, and it works fine.
However I discovered that reading the application's SharedPreferences from a broadcast receiver caused some problems (It read an older version of those preferences, probably due to a different PID)

I were told that to do what I needed to do, I should call an Activity, that solved the SharedPreferences problem, but created a new one.

The activity must run in the background exclusively. It is essentially a heartbeat, sending off some information to a Presence solution, keeping the users presence alive.

The Alarm Receiver:
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

The activity in the manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

The Alarm Activity only sends an HTTP update, but even if I remove all but the super.onCreate line, it still forces the application into the foreground, and focus. But it only happens if the application itself is only "minimized" via the home button. If I close it with the back button, it won't get forced into focus, while the heartbeat still fires just fine in the background.

How can I prevent this?

I'm developing for API version 7 (Android 2.1), but can update to API 8 if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `Service` for performing background tasks.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Do I need to do something to end the service task? Like the Activity "finish()" method call?

Comment: Thanks. This is one of those cases where the right word triggers the right solution to an annoying problem, and everything else just snaps into place right after :)